# Can a power's effects be triggered by the power itself?

Tags: dnd-4e

Specifically, can a sorcerer with the Arcane Admixture Lightning (Flame Spiral) and Mark of Storm feats trigger Flame Spiral's damage through the slide granted by hitting with Flame Spiral?

I'm not sure of the order of events in Flame Spiral's hit and effect lines. Are there rules specific to the resolution order of events in an attack power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the power. In this case, no.

Powers are read and performed in the order that they are written (RC 92). This one proceeds:

- Target
- Hit
- Effect

The effect is not in play when the hit line is adjudicated, and the slide from Mark of Storm is performed as part of the hit line, and thus the effect line is not yet in play when it happens.

There is, however, no explicit rule that prevents a power from triggering itself (and in fact, many powers would not work at all if this was the case), so you don't have to worry about that. The only problem is whether the part of the power that you want to trigger is in effect when you would  trigger it (the case here, it is not).

Comment: In case you want to cite it somehow, Rules Compendium p92 is the one that talks about executing lines in a power in sequence. PHB1 doesn't seem to mention it in their description of reading powers.

Comment: It's potentially worth noting that none of the character optimization communities agree with you on this adjudication. Of course, being optimization communities, it's in their nature to not trend towards adjudications that limit the power of certain combinations.